# Oracle Developer Suite after installation login

Tags: authentication, oracle10g, installation

i downloaded Oracle Developer Suite 10g from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/developer-suite/downloads/101202winsoft-087370.html and i started installing.Chose complete installation and it started installing.At no point did it ask me for an admin password.It just installed.Now i am trying to run mysql and it asks for username,password and database.I searched the internet for solutions.Tried with sys/manager/sysdba system/manager/sysdba as i saw some solutions it didn't work.I reinstalled it 2 more time in hope to see a button where i can configure the admin password.Nothing

Need help.What am i missing?How can i fix this ?

Thank you

Comment: That's a development suite, not a database. You can use it to connect to an oracle database to developer stuff. You mentioned mysql, but the usernames you listed and your tag indicates oracle. What database are you using, and have you actually installed it?